# How Salesforce org behaves after enabling my domain

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-development

I need to build a Lightning App in an old org, and as a prerequisite, My Domain must be enabled.

However, there are couple things to take into consideration:

1. Will the login change to My Domain login URL for all internal and external users?
2. Will the URL instance for the My Domain stay the same for every release onwards?

I hope you guys can provide some more details since Salesforce documentation doesn't provide explicit information regarding this topics from what I've researched. Thanks a lot!